# Add value to field using hook_webform_submission_presave()

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I am at my wits end trying to use the hook_webform_submission_presave function on a webform that I have created for a Drupal 7 site. Ideally I would like to capture a list of nodes that a user has flagged and transfer that data into a field before the user submits their form. But the function is just not adding the data.

First I get the flags:

```
$flags = flag_get_user_flags($node->type);
```

Then I want to transfer that variable into a field with a component ID of 32.

```
// Update some component's value before it is saved.
  $component_id = 32;
  $submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0] = $flags;
```

Here is the full function:

```
function get_flags_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
$nodes_list = array();
$title = '';
  // Get the flags.
  $flags = flag_get_user_flags($node->type);

  // Get the nodes.
  if (!empty($flags)) {
foreach ($flags as $flag) {
    $nid = $flad->entity_id;
    // Get node data. Delete to not get node titles.
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $title = $node->title;
    // Combine data.
    $nodes_list[] .= 'node/' . $nid . ' ' . $title . ",\n";
    }
  }

  // Update some component's value before it is saved.
  $component_id = 32;
  $submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0] = $nodes_list;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd love some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, you should not have created another question out of this. This is a probably a [duplicte of the original question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111293/ability-for-user-to-flag-or-select-multiple-nodes-from-view-listing) now. The function that I initially gave you, handles flags correctly. Please see:

```
function leadflag_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
  $nodes_list = '';
  $title = '';
  // Get the flags.
  $flags = flag_get_user_flags('node');
  // Get the nodes.
  if (!empty($flags)) {
    $flags = $flags['flag_name'];
    foreach ($flags as $flag) {
        $nid = $flag->entity_id;
      // Get node data. Delete to not get node titles.
      $node = node_load($nid);
      $title = $node->title;
      // Combine data.
      $nodes_list .= 'node/' . $nid . ' ' . $title . ",\n";
    }
  }

  // Update some component's value before it is saved.
  $component_id = 4;
  $submission->data[$component_id][0] = $nodes_list;
}
```

**1. The foreach part should not be removed.** Flags is an array of objects, and you can't assign it to a field value, which expects a string. You can only remove the two lines I indicated in a comment if you want to.

**2. This should g in a module, not in a theme.** You should substitute the 'MYMODULE' in this code with a name of the module, where it is placed. How to create a simple module is among the other links I indicated back at your original question/answer.

You need to follow the steps I outlined in the original question. Here is with more detail:

1. Create the module. Replace the function name part 'leadflag' with the name of your module.
2. Clear the website (Drupal) cache.
3. Replace the component_id with the correct one (see how in the original answer).
4. Replace the fid of the flag with your actual fid.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I probably should not have created a new question. Just to clarify, I have done each of your steps in detail: 1) Created a module, activated it, Renamed MYMODULE to the module name "get_flags" as that is my module folder/name, created a webform field with id of "32", cleared cache. I still get no value in the text field after submission of the form. I even tried $submission->data[32]['value'][0] = 'Testing'; and nothing was returned. I think your code is right, but it's not accessing my form. I have no idea why.

Comment: Then you need to debug if form is accessed at all. Immediately after the $submission->data line, add this line: watchdog('Webform Submission', 'Added data for: ' . $node->nid); After you submit a webform the next time, look at the Drupal log and see if that entry gets there. BTW, you have replaced MYMODULE with get_flags as well, correct? :)

Comment: Alexei, the watchdog statement worked. In the log it reads "Added data for 27225". Yes, I replaced MYMODULE with "get_flags". That is also the name of my module which is located in the sites/all/modules folder. Is it a problem that I have multiple webforms and there are duplicate component id's in each webform. This module is not targeting a specific webform. Is that a problem? Or should it target all webforms that have the same component id? The webform I am using is '27225'. What should I try next?

Comment: Now try to see if you actually get the content. Change the line to watchdog('Webform Submission', 'Flagged list: ' . $nodes_list);

Comment: Interesting. It gives me "Flagged list: Array".

Comment: Yes, I see. My fault - I forgot to turn an array into a string. I have corrected the function. Please copy it's content over and retry. Now, test with this: watchdog('Webform Submission', 'Flagged list: ' . $comma_list); - The $comma_list variable should contain the list string, with '; ' as separator.

Comment: Ok I replaced it and I get the same "Flagged list: Array".

Comment: More changes to function. Try again please. Should not be an array this time. Sorry for the hassle. The variable is again $nodes_list.

Comment: I copied your code again and placed in the watchdog with the new $nodes_list and I get the same "Flagged list: Array".

Comment: I cant believe it. I need to see what you have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14322/discussion-between-dan-and-alexei-rayu)

Answer (score 0):

`flag_get_user_flags` will return an array. so you have to handle it as an array not like a value.